# Permission problems when altering a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this piece of code that should set a custom format number depending on the value of the cell.

```
function fixFormat() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange("K1:K30");

  var rows = range.getNumRows();
  var cols = range.getNumColumns();
  for(var row = 1; row <= rows; row++) {
    for(var col = 1; col <= cols; col++) {
      var cell = range.getCell(row, col);
      var value = cell.getValue();
      if (value > 1000) {
        cell.setNumberFormat("#.###B");
      } else {
        cell.setNumberFormat("#.###");
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

When configured as a trigger (onChange) it does not run at all, when called as `=fixFormat()` I get the error: `You don't have permission to call setNumberFormat.`

- I am the owner of the sheet
- I have not blocked access to anything
- I had the same script working on other sheets

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Looks like there is a typo error in line 3 of this code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, but that is not the problem. That was a comment that I did not completely erase when transcribing here on SO

Comment: Yes, i know i wasn't the prblm. anyways i have tried what you have described. and everything works fine on my side.

Comment: please share a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem

After a lot of digging, the [support page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services) says:

> Spreadsheet: Read only (can use most get*() methods, but not set*()). Cannot open other spreadsheets (SpreadsheetApp.openById() or SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()).

So the solution (barely) is to use [custom menus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services)